# "Unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``" on cron job

Tags: cron

I set up a cron job on my server running RedHat 4.1 to backup MySQL databases, and then upload to Amazon S3. The goal is to drop the .bz2 file in a folder corresponding with the day of the week. However, I'm getting the following error mailed to me by daemon.

Cron job:

```
MAILTO=backups@example.com
0       4       *       *       *       mysqldump --all-databases  -ubackups -pPassword | gzip > all-databases.sql.bz2; s3cmd put all-databases.sql.bz2 s3://backup_exampleserver.com/mysql_backups/`date +%A`/all-databases.sql.bz2
```

Error message:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: I recommend to put this stuff in a regular shell script and then call this shell script from cron. This way, you can save you a lot of trouble and make the job a lot easier to understand and debug.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to escape the percent sign in your command with a backslash: `\%`, otherwise it is interpreted as the end of command.

From *crontab*(5):

```
The command field (the rest of the line) is the command to be run.  The
entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or % character, will
be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the SHELL variable of
the crontab.  Percent signs (‘%’) in the command, unless escaped with a
backslash (‘\’), will be changed into newline characters, and all data
after the first ‘%’ will be sent to the command as standard input.
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the clarification. New to cron, so much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Change this:

```
`date +%A`
```

to:

```
`date +\%A`
```